# Gradle setup for project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ant, build.gradle

I'm a Gradle beginner, yet I inherited a Java project that's using Gradle. That particular project depends on another Java project which is Ant build project on separate disk location.

In order for Gradle to build I have somehow to tell him there's another project which should be considered, but whatever I tried, I failed. This is my current project setup:

```
git Folder
|
|
---AntProject
             |
              -src
---GradleProject
                |
                |
                -proper Gradle file / folder structure
```

Now, in my Gradle project in settings.gradle I added this:

```
include ':AntProject'
project(':AntProject').projectDir = file("C:\\<absolutePathToBeSure>\\git\\AntProject\\")
```

In build.gradle I have added this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":AntProject")
}
```

When I try doing "Gradle refresh" I'm getting error:

```
project declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in descriptor for project :AntProject
```

What should I do?

Notes:

- I tried using "\" instead of "\" inside settings.gradle, no help
- I can't migrate AntProject to Gradle, move it to another location or influence it, that project is solely maintained by another dev.

Answer (score 0):

If the ant project is not Gradle (it doesn't own the `build.gradle` script) Gradle will not know what to do with it and adding it to `settings.gradle` will not help.

You can use ant library in Gradle to do what you wish to do, below are some docs how to use Ant in Gradle. I believe best is to not include it to not confuse Gradle and then create a custom task that will do what you need based on the directory `$rootProject/antProject`

The [import_ant_build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#sec:import_ant_build) section looks promising

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html

Comment: Aha, ok, but will that actually integrate AntProject into my own project? That ant project is a sort of "Common" and GradleProject is using and importing classes from that "AntProject"

Comment: not sure what you mean integrate, it is some sort of integration already.

Comment: Well jar file built by gradle.build located inside Gradle project will automatically contain sources of both And and Gradle projects, right?

Comment: I tried adding new "build.gradle" file to AntProject. That file i populated according to instructions here https://objectpartners.com/2017/05/04/easily-convert-from-ant-to-gradle/ Thins i already had in "setting" worked then but after i refreshed the Gradle project it went ok BUT that converted AntProject to Gradle buildship and messed with all libs from Ant project build path.... :D